# Getting student grades with their names

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement, math, equation-solving

I am trying to write this code with more efficient way.. I just couldn't figure it out (as you see if statements doesn't look nice) The problem is pretty simple.. I need to get students name at first, then their grades.. something like

`James - 45, Kevin -51, Karen - 78, Jessica -64`

and I want my output will be  like..  James -Failed , Kevin -Failed , Karen -Passed,Jessica -Passed

```
a =[]
b=[]
for i in range(0,4):
    name = input("Name:")
    a.append(name)
    for j in range(0,1):
        grade = int(input("Exam Grade:"))
        b.append(grade)

average =(sum(b)/len(b))


if(b[0]<average):
    print("{}- Failed".format(a[0]))
if(b[1]<average):
    print("{}- Failed".format(a[1]))
if(b[2]<average):
    print("{}- Failed".format(a[2]))
if(b[3]<average):
    print("{}- Failed".format(a[3]))
if(b[0]>average):
    print("{}- Passed".format(a[0]))
if(b[1]>average):
    print("{}- Passed".format(a[1]))
if(b[2]>average):
    print("{}- Passed".format(a[2]))
if(b[3]>average):
    print("{}- Passed".format(a[3]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = []
b = []

for i in range(4):
    a.append(input("Name: "))
    b.append(int(input("Exam Grade: ")))

average = (sum(b)/len(b))

for i in range(4):
    if b[i] < average:
        print("{} - Failed".format(a[i]))
    else:
        print("{} - Passed".format(a[i]))
```

You can also use a dictionary of names-grades instead of two lists.

Comment: yes! that's what I'm talking about.. thanks for the answer sir

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using loop in your if else statement??

```
a =[]
b=[]
for i in range(0,4):
    name = input("Name:")
a.append(name)
for j in range(0,1):
    grade = int(input("Exam Grade:"))
    b.append(grade)

average =(sum(b)/len(b))
for k in range(0,4):
if(b[k]<average):
 print("{}- Failed".format(a[k]))
else:
    print("{}- Passed".format(a[k]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for loop` before your `if statements` as so:

```
for each in b:
    if each < average:
        print("{}- Failed".format(a[each]))
    elif each > average:
        print("{}- Passed".format(a[each]))
```

So this for loop will iterate through the whole list of grades stored in `b`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `for` loop for grade input. Try the following script:

```
a,b = [],[] 
for i in range(4):
  a.append(input("Name: "))
  b.append(int(input("Grade: ")))

avg = sum(b)/len(b)
for i in range(4):
  if b[i] < avg:
    print(f"{a[i]} - Failed")
  else:
    print(f"{a[i]} - Passed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
all_stud = {}
for i in range(0,4):
    name = input("Name:")
    grade = int(input("Exam Grade:"))
    all_stud[name] = grade

average =(sum(all_stud.values())/len(all_stud))

print({f"{i} - Failed" if v <= average else f"{i} - Passed" for i, v in all_stud.items() })
```